# jQuery: Appeding tr to table tbody prevents tr click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After executing a query, a table row is added, good, it gives the user the option to delete that row with a Delete button, here is when things start to get fussy, any function related to the appended tr just won't work,even when I changed the button.click to a whole tr, it deletes the headers tr and every other table tr except for the appended ones!

Just to clarify, the table is inside a form that is not #codbar

```
$('#codbar').submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/GoogleStore/ajax/venta.php",
            data: {'iditem': $('#id-item').val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data, status, jqXhr)
            {
                var i = 0;
                var end = parseInt($('input[name = "contador"]').val());
                for(i = 0; i <= end; i++)
                {
                    if($('input[name = "cod'+i+'"]').length && $('input[name = "cod'+i+'"]').val() == data["Cod"])
                    {
                        $('input[name = "cant'+i+'"]').val(parseInt($('input[name = "cant'+i+'"]').val()) + 1);
                        $('span[name = "total'+i+'"]').text(parseFloat($('input[name = "cant'+i+'"]').val()) * parseFloat($('input[name = "precio'+i+'"]').val()));
                        i = end;
                    }
                    else if(i == end)
                    {
                        $('input[name = "contador"]').val();
                        $('table[name = "venta"]').find('tbody').append($('<tr><td><span>'+data["Prod"]+'</span></td><td><input type="hidden" name="cod'+i+'" value="'+data["Cod"]+'"><span>'+data["Cod"]+'</span></td><td><input type="text" name="cant'+i+'" value="1"></td><td><input type="hidden" name="precio'+i+'" value="'+data["Precio"]+'"><span>'+data["Precio"]+'</span></td><td><span name="total'+i+'">'+data["Precio"]+'</span></td><td><input type="button" class="red" name="DeleteRow" value="Eliminar"></td></tr>'));
                        $('input[name = "contador"]').val(end + 1);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log("Error response:", jqXhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    $("input[name = 'DeleteRow']").click(function()
    {
        alert('');
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow', function()
        {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Events on dynamic HTML wont work. Either use Live or On for binding events.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that, I'm kind of a rookie to jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate the event to the static parent:

```
$(document).on('click', "button[value = 'Eliminar']", function()
```

change to this as above.

---

Because you are appending the `tr` dynamically so any event registered on static elements won't be bound on newly created element.

Comment: It worked! Thank you, mind explaining why exactly?

Comment: @Jofran dynamically created element wasn't part of the dom, so the event bound on a static button/dom node won't be registered for new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $("table[name = "venta"]").on("click","button[value = 'Eliminar']",function()
    {
        alert('');
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow', function()
        {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    });
```